# Oracle Ref Cursor ADODB - Why am I getting PLS-00306 wrong number of types of arguments

Tags: excel, vba, oracle, oracle11g, adodb

Trying to return a recordset from Oracle. The procedure has an input parameter with datatype **Number** and an in/out parameter with Oracle's **ref cursor** datatype.

Getting error:

> PLS-00306 wrong number of types of arguments in call to "get_random_tube_colors_pr".

#### Oracle

```
procedure get_random_tube_colors_pr(in_tube_color_id in number,
                                tubeset in out tubetab)
```

#### VBA

```vb
conStr = "User ID=ops$scxpoly;Password=password;Data Source=source;Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;"

With db
  If .state = adStateClosed Then
     .ConnectionString = conStr
     .CursorLocation = adUseClient
     .Open
  End If
End With

With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = db
    .NamedParameters = False    
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandText = "OPS$SCXPOLY.mfg_tube_colors_pk.get_random_tube_colors_pr"       
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("in_tube_color_id", adBigInt, adParamInput, , 2679)
    .Properties("PLSQLRSet") = True
    Set rst = .Execute()
    MsgBox Err.Number & vbNewLine & Err.Description
End with
```

I commented out .CreateParameter calling Oracle's ref cursor datatype:

```
'   .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("tubeset", adVariant, adParamReturnValue)
```

But same error - [Call Oracle stored procedure with VBA using a refcursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42556484/call-oracle-stored-procedure-with-vba-using-a-refcursor)

Added `Properties("PLSQLRSet") = TRUE` but still same issue
 - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b28431/using.htm

Also set `.NamedParameters = True`, no go.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you sure `tubetab` is a ref cursor, and not a collection?

Comment: @AlexPoole I'm not sure. Trying to confirm. If it is a collection and not ref cursor, how should I handle that?

Comment: Did you already test the stored procedure by calling it with pl/sql in Sql/Developer? Just to make sure `tubetab` is the right data type.